# Expand a string of slice by delimiter

Tags: string, go, slice

I want to expand a string of slice by delimiter "/".

For example, expanding the following slice

```
s := []string{"5/3","9","5/4/1","6"}
```

Should produce individual slices :

```
["5","9","5","6"] ["5","9","4","6"] ["5","9","1","6"]
["3","9","5","6"] ["3","9","4","6"] ["3","9","1","6"]
```

I am pretty much stuck here

```
var c [][]string{}
s := []string{"5/3","9","5/4/1","6"}
for _, v := range s {
    combos := strings.Split(v, "/")
    for _, combo := range combos {

    }       
}
```

Comment: FYI, the terminology you're looking for here is "expansion".

Comment: You really want people here to do your homework?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because homework.

Comment: @Volker: Read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).

Comment: @Volker I am not sure what do you mean by homework question. I was stuck with the logic here which was explained in answer by ssemilla below. I can see similar kind of questions upvoted several times in other programming languages.


P.S. I am not sure how many university courses are based on golang to give homeworks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running time aside, you can achieve this with recursion.

```
func Perm(digits [][]string) (perm [][]string) {

    if len(digits) == 0 || len(digits) == 1 {
        return digits
    }

    nextDigits := Perm(digits[1:])
    for _, digit := range digits[0] {
        for _, next := range nextDigits {
            cat := append([]string{digit}, next...)
            perm = append(perm, cat)
        }
    }

    return perm
}
```

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/uq-XuPSz171)